# Convert time from seconds to hours, with rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, data-conversion

I need to convert time from seconds to hours with 2 decimal rounding
`PeriodLength` contains time in seconds.

`(c.PeriodLength)/3600. as Time`

Returns time in hours but result is like `1.250000`
and I need it to be `1.25`.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Are you looking for [**ROUND()**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012, with team foundation server database.

Comment: "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012" is not a DBMS, it's a client tool. But as that can only connect to Microsoft SQL Server, that the DBMS you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard SQL, you can convert it to a decimal.  Something like:

```
select cast(c.PeriodLength / (60.00*60) as decimal(6, 2));
```

There are also database specific solutions, but you don't specify the database.

Comment: this code is rounding and hour and fifteen minutes to 1.00

Comment: SOme databases do integer division for two integers.  The fix is to use numeric constants with a decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET value = ROUND(value,2)
```

Note that this is generally used for statistical purposes, rather than monetary or time. However, it should work for what you are seeking.

Comment: how would i use this in a select statement? (Round((c.PeriodLength)/3600)2) does not work

Comment: `select round((c.PeriodLength/3600), 2) as PeriodHrs` should get you there.

Comment: this code rounded to the nearest integer. if i put round((c.PeriodLength/3600.), 2) as PeriodHrs then it retured 1.25000